# Share on google plus android if Google Plus app is disabled

Tags: android, google-plus, share

I am looking for a scenario where my google plus app is disabled and I need to share image on google plus. Please suggest how to do that?

```
    try{
        PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
        share.setText("Just testing about the things of google play");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        share.setStream(uri);
        share.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), 0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Util.showToast(this, "Please install Google Plus to share with");
    }
```

Have found this code on google plus documentation but its not working if app is disabled.

Comment: Please explain the reason of downvote